# Extraction of sub string from the text using R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a string data as follows:

```
a<-  "\n    Update Your Profile to Dissolve This Message\nSocial Media Learning and behaviour\n        Uploaded on May 3, 2020 at 10:56 in Research\n            View Forum\n        \n"
```

I have to extract the string "Social Media Learning and behaviour" for this I used the below code:

```
gsub("        Uploaded on .* ", "", gsub("\n    Update Your Profile to Dissolve This Message\n", "",a))
```

This gives me output as below

```
"Social Media Learning and behaviour\n\n"
```

I am not able to match the exact pattern. What can be the exact pattern to extract "Social Media Learning and behaviour" without "\n\n"

Comment: You could also match the line before in a capturing group, and match the line after it that contains Uploaded `^(.*)\r?\n        Uploaded on` https://regex101.com/r/bF5GKT/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract part between `"Update Your Profile to Dissolve This Message"` and `"Uploaded on"`

```
sub(".*Update Your Profile to Dissolve This Message\n(.*)\n\\s+Uploaded on.*", "\\1", a)
#[1] "Social Media Learning and behaviour"
```

You can also use `str_match` from `stringr`

```
stringr::str_match(a, "Update Your Profile to Dissolve This Message\n(.*)\n\\s+Uploaded on")[, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could capture the previous line in a group and match the next line that contains Uploaded:

```
(.*)\r?\n[^\S\r\n]+Uploaded on
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8xL2Gx/1)

```
a<-  "\n    Update Your Profile to Dissolve This Message\nSocial Media Learning and behaviour\n        Uploaded on May 3, 2020 at 10:56 in Research\n            View Forum\n        \n"
stringr::str_match(a, "(.*)\\r?\\n[^\\S\\r\\n]+Uploaded on")
```